# scalaz.concurrent.Task repeatEval only evaluate Task.now and Task.async once

Tags: scala, scalaz

I am learning scalaz stream at the moment, I am confused why repeatEval only evaluate Task.async once.

```
  val result = Process
    .repeatEval(Task.async[Unit](t => {
      val result = scala.io.Source.fromURL("http://someUrl").mkString
      println(".......")
      println(result)
    }))

  result.runLog.run //only print once
```

However, if I change Task.async to Task.delay. It evaluates the function infinitely. I dont know why is that

```
 val result = Process
    .repeatEval(Task.delay({
      val result = scala.io.Source.fromURL("http://someUrl").mkString
      println(".......")
      println(result)
    }))

result.runLog.run //print infinitely
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35592498/334519) to your other question—it seems like you're looking for `Task.apply` in this case, not `Task.async`).

Comment: Are you saying the reason to evaluate only once is due to async argument is a callback ?

Comment: Not exactly—the argument to `async` is being evaluated synchronously (funnily enough), since it's intended to be a registration function, not code to be run asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mention in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35592498/334519) to your recent question about `Task`, `Task.async` takes a function that registers callbacks—not some code that should be executed asynchronously. In the case of the other question, you actually want `Task.async`, since you're interoperating with a callback-based API.

Here it seems like you probably want `Task.apply`, not `Task.delay`. The two look similar, but `delay` simply suspends the computation—it doesn't use an `ExecutorService` to run it in a separate thread. You can see this in the following  example:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._, concurrent._

val delayTask = Task.delay(Thread.sleep(5000))
val applyTask = Task(Thread.sleep(5000))

Nondeterminism[Task].both(delayTask, delayTask).run
Nondeterminism[Task].both(applyTask, applyTask).run
```

The `delayTask` version will take longer.